# Edit Footer line color css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I edit color of this white footer line in CSS?

Website: https://neue-horizonte.info/

[image: The footer]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please read comment above.. btw this is definitly NOT a WHITE footer ;)

Answer (score -3):

```
<style>
footer .mkdf-footer-bottom-inner.mkdf-grid{
  border-top-color: red !important;
}
</style>
```